# dynamically set #options for checkboxes

Tags: forms, ajax

I have a problem with form. I would like to create checkboxes dynamically, based on the value from select type field.  I have created AJAX callback function and in this function, I create a list and then return it to form.

```
my_ajax_callback($form, $form_state) {  
  $form['fieldset3']['service']["#title"] = 'new title';
  $form['fieldset3']['service']["#options"] = array('test1','test2');
  return $form['fieldset3']['service']["#options"];
}
```

This function sets the new title but doesn't create new options in that field.
If I change the type to 'select' it works fine.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I'm having same problem, did you find any solution for it?